# Customizing the cassini webserver

Tags: visual-studio-2008, localhost, cassini, visual-web-developer

Currently the local webserver exectutes at http://localhost:51377

Is there any option of customizing the web server in order executing under http://192.168.1.2:51377 (where 192.168.1.2 is my static intranet ip address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassini will only serve local requests. If you want a lightweight webserver you may want to take a look at [UltiDev](http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/)

Comment: Any idea how can I download UltiDev via http proxy?

Answer (score 4):

I just released the CassiniDev 3.5.1/4.0.1 beta with a simple test fixture example if you are interested.

Supports arbitrary IP and Host name

Cassini for Developers and Testers: http://cassinidev.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is for allowing other people on your network to connect to your development server, the answer is no.  Cassini is specifically built to reject any outside connections.

If for some reason you need to reroute it, you could add an alias in your hosts file to redirect "localhost" to 192.168.1.2 instead of 127.0.0.1.  I've never tried this, and it may not work anyway, due to the above mentioned reason - Cassini may interpret it as an outside connection.

Comment: actually i would like to debug a piece of code locally with requests coming from a webpage

Comment: Publish it to your IIS server, and then use "Attach to process" to attach to w3wp.exe from Visual Studio.  You'll be able to debug the code every time someone hits your IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can easily just use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to redirect requests from an arbitrary address to the Cassini loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

you can patch cassini(WebDev.WebServer.exe) to unlock the localhost loopback restriction --> 
http://eeichinger.blogspot.com/2009/12/sniff-http-traffic-with-aspnet.html

In other words, allow outside connections and debug them inside Visual Stuido :-)