# How can I configure Cassini web server to accept requests to different hosts?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, cassini

See duplicate: [Customizing the cassini webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133615/customizing-the-cassini-webserver)

---

I have a web service hosted using Cassini web server. It works fine if I reference it by localhost, but when I use my machine's name (even using the browser locally), I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden.
Version Information: Cassini Web Server 1.0.40305.0
```

How can I configure it to accept all requests?

Comment: When you ping localhost what IP address does it resolve to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassini is specifically build to reject any outside connections. You could rebuild from [sourcecode](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) if you want it to accept outside connections.

Edit:

In reply to the below comment on what to edit in the sourcecode, you'd probably want to change the following in `Server.cs` on line 88:

```
_socket = CreateSocketBindAndListen(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
             IPAddress.Loopback, _port);
```

Into something like this:

```
_socket = CreateSocketBindAndListen(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
             IPAddress.Any, _port);
```

This will bind the listening socket to all available IP addresses on the system instead of only to the localhost address (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Is there really no other way?

Comment: You might also try UltiDev Cassini (http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) This seems to be based on the original MS Cassini but with some added features. Haven't tried it though so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Grzenio, could you please point out what specifically in the code has to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

To update this answer, IIS Express is a new alternative that allows this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To avoid anyone else having to go further, if you need a lightweight web server for *production* use, IIS-Express is **not** recommended (by themselves) for that purpose .